# How to take values from several csv files and add to dictionary with a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I ran a CNN model with data broken out in five folds, through 20 epochs and got the loss value of each epoch run per fold.  I saved the loss values from each epoch to a csv file without the index, so I have five files - one for each epoch.  I now want to take those five files and compile them into a dataframe with two columns, one = the fold number and the other is the loss value.

I have been running into a lot of issues with trying to do this.  First I thought I could take the dataframe created when I import the csv, and convert this to a list and then add the values from the list to the dataframe with a value of the fold number in that column.  I was receiving errors when trying to append to the dataframe.

This is my code:

```
loss_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["fold", "loss"])

for i in range(len(loss_file_list)):
    loss = pd.read_csv(path+loss_file_list[i]).values.tolist()
    for j in range(len(loss)):
        loss_list['fold'] = i+1
        loss_list.loc[i+j*(i+1)]['fold'].append(loss[j][0])
```

The error I receive is:

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1153, in _LocIndexer._get_label(self, label, axis)
   1151 def _get_label(self, label, axis: int):
   1152     # GH#5667 this will fail if the label is not present in the axis.
-> 1153     return self.obj.xs(label, axis=axis)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3864, in NDFrame.xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3862             new_index = index[loc]
   3863 else:
-> 3864     loc = index.get_loc(key)
   3866     if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):
   3867         if loc.dtype == np.bool_:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3631, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630 except KeyError as err:
-> 3631     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632 except TypeError:
   3633     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3634     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3635     #  the TypeError.
   3636     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 0
```

I am really at a loss for what to do now.  If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
loss_dict = {0: [], 1: [], 2:[], 3:[], 4:[]}

for i in range(len(loss_file_list)):
    loss = pd.read_csv(path+loss_file_list[i]).values.tolist()
    for j in range(len(loss)):
        loss_dict[i].append(loss[j][0])
```